# System directories on separate partitions shown on desktop as #.# GB Volume

Tags: mount, xfce, fstab

During the install of Ubuntu studio WW 15.10 (XFCE4), I put /usr/share and /var/www on separate partitions.  As expected they were added to fstab to auto mount on startup.  The strange thing is that the one mounted as /usr/share is on my desktop as "#.#GB Volume". It may not hurt anything, but is very annoying.  They are not mounted through /media, /mnt, or /home so they should not be on my desktop if I understand corectly.

So why is this happening, and how can I fix this odd behavior?  I do not want to hide all drive Icons from my desktop, I know how to do that, so save your time and please do not suggest it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is embarrassing, but it helps to make sure you have the right UUID's in the right places in fstab:

I added the UUID from the partition of /usr/share to another partition (near identical size) that I wanted mounted on startup through /media/..., so I had it in there twice, and got no errors or trouble by doing so!  So it seams you can mount partitions twice, at different mount points and with different names, which just may come in handy if needed.

Words of advice:  Use partition labels for clarity.  When copying UUID's, check them, check them again, and check them one more time after pasting into fstab, or you may have a lot of work on your hands if the system doesn't boot.  I got lucky this time, checking twice was insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning on mounting those partitions in the future, you can create a `udev` file to hide those partitions from showing up.

Create a file in your `rules.d` folder.  I called mine `10-hide-partitions.rules`

```
sudo mousepad /etc/udev/rules.d/10-hide-partitions.rules
```

and I added in the following to hide the partition.  (This one is assuming the partition is `/dev/sdb1`)

```
KERNEL=="sdb1",ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

after the file is saved, run the `udevadm` to activate your changes

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

---

If you want to unhide those in the future, change the `"1"` to `"0"`.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Terrance,  I may have use for that info in the future, but I figured out what was going on,  so I will have to answer my own question, although with some embarrassment.

Comment: @BobZoid No problem!  We're here to help!  =)